# How to divide data with K-Means clustering in Python

Tags: python, k-means

i divided my data to 4 parts using K-Means clustering algorithm. I visualize it , but now i need each cluster as dataframe. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: give us more info please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use **SKlearn** for clustering than you can use `predict` to classify each data point per [cluster](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans.predict) and save it to a dictionary (as an example).

Then you can use `from_records` method from **Pandas** to [convert](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) the dictionary to the DataFrame.